# How can I use get_bloginfo('admin_email') in a custom PHP file?

Tags: customization, bloginfo, phpmailer

How can I use **get_bloginfo('admin_email')** in a custom PHP file located in the parent theme root directory?

I've built a custom form and a PHP mail script separately, but now I'd like to send the form data to the WP Admin email address with Bcc.

```
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <example@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: <'. get_bloginfo('admin_email');'>'. "\r\n";

    mail("example2@gmail.com","Form Application",$admin_email_body,$headers);
```

Do I need to include Wordpress functions in the PHP file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the `wp-load.php` in your PHP file, but, I do not recommend this method. It's better you use the `wp_enqueue_script()`.

See [this article](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) to get more information.

```
<?php
include "../../../wp-load.php";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <example@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: <'. get_bloginfo('admin_email') . '>'. "\r\n";


mail("example2@gmail.com","Form Application",$admin_email_body,$headers);
```